# Laravel 6.0, Queued jobs aren't queued on the server

Tags: linux, laravel, queue, supervisord

I have the video creation processes which are taking about 3-5 minutes. I've done it as a background tasks using Laravel `Events`, `Listeners` and `Queues`

**Changes**

In the `.env` file

```
QUEUE_CONNECTION=database
```

Created both `jobs` and `failed_jobs` tables in DB.

***CreateVideoEvent***

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

class CreateVideoEvent
{

    public $video_data;

    public function __construct($video_data)
    {
        $this->video_data = $video_data;
    }
}
```

***CreateVideoListener***

```
<?php

namespace App\Listeners;

use App\Events\CreateVideoEvent;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class CreateVideoListener implements ShouldQueue
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    public function handle($event)
    {
        // Run video create commands
    }
}
```

***Supervisor***

```
[program:laravel-queue]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /var/www/project_folder/artisan queue:work --tries=5 --timeout=600
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=root
numprocs=8
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/var/www/project_folder/worker.log
```

When the video creation process should start, it's adding an event and a queue job to DB.

```
event(new CreateVideoEvent($video_data));
```

So, the problem is when the 1st job starts working ( it takes about 3-5 minutes ), and I'm creating the 2nd video before the first one is completed, it starts the 2nd video creation process before the 1st one is completed. So, basically, the jobs aren't queued and it's causing an issue as both video creation processes stops working.

Maybe I've missed something, or have you an idea what can be the reason of this?

Comment: Is it possible that there is more than one worker available to pick up jobs from the queue? See: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queues#rate-limiting

Comment: I don't think that there is another worker as before adding the supervisor, I was needed to run the ```php artisan queue:work``` manually to run the video creation process. But it would explain the issue